# Calculating TOTAL of certain items using CASE and OVER

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, case, window-functions, cumulative-sum

I need to calculate the total value of specific product codes. The product codes are 5780 and everything below 5700.

To calculate the value I use the code:

```
CASE WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5870 THEN [ICP].[UnitCost] * SUM(Sum([PL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk])  / @Credits) OVER (PARTITION BY [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] )
WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5730 THEN ([ICP].[UnitCost] - 0.25) * SUM(Sum([PL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk])  / @Credits) OVER (PARTITION BY [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] )
WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5990 THEN ([ICP].[UnitCost] * 0 ) * SUM(Sum([PL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk])  / @Credits) OVER (PARTITION BY [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] )
ELSE [ICP].[UnitCost] * SUM(Sum([PL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk])  / @Credits) OVER (PARTITION BY [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] )
END
```

The `ELSE`part is what relates to the product codes I need for this section of the report.

I tried using two different formulas and they both return different amounts but not the correct amount.

One is:

```
CASE WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5780 OR [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] < 5700 THEN SUM(Sum([PL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk])  / @Credits * [ICP].[UnitCost] )
OVER ()
END
```

And the other is:

```
SUM(Sum([PL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk])  / @Credits * [ICP].[UnitCost]) OVER
       (PARTITION BY (CASE WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] IN (5870, 5730, 5990)
                           THEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] 
                           END) 
       )
```

They group the product codes correctly by displaying the same number for each, but the calculated number is incorrect.

Sample output:

```
    Product Category Code | Value  |
    5870                  | 100    |
    5730                  | 400    |
    5990                  | 200    |
    5780                  | 200    |
    1111                  | 50     |  
    2222                  | 175    |  
    3333                  | 500    |  
    4444                  | 125    |  

    Total Value: 1050 
It has to ignore product code 5870, 5990, and 5730 and not include 
those in the total value.
```

I am using Microsoft SQL Sever 2005.
Let me know if I need to explain further.

Whole Code:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
DECLARE @Credits Decimal(19,8);
DECLARE @Price Decimal(19,8);

SET @Credits = 41000;
SET @Price = 1.57;

SELECT 
     CASE WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5870 THEN 'Trimmings' 
WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5730 THEN 'Rib Tips'
WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5990 THEN 'Skins'
ELSE [PC].[Description1] 
END AS [Description]
   , SUM(SUM(PL.OriginalQuantity_Stk)) OVER
 (PARTITION BY (CASE WHEN PC.ProductCategoryCode IN (5870, 5730, 5990)
 THEN PC.ProductCategoryCode
 END)
) AS [Total Weight]
   , Sum(CASE WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] <> 5870 THEN [PL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk] 
WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] <> 5730 THEN [PL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk] 
WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] <> 5990 THEN [PL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk] 
END) AS [Weight]
   , @Credits - SUM(Sum([PL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk])) OVER () AS [Shrink]
   , CASE WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5870 THEN SUM(Sum([PL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk]) / @Credits) OVER (PARTITION BY [PC].[ProductCategoryCode]) 
WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5730 THEN SUM(Sum([PL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk]) / @Credits) OVER (PARTITION BY [PC].[ProductCategoryCode])
WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5990 THEN SUM(Sum([PL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk]) / @Credits) OVER (PARTITION BY [PC].[ProductCategoryCode])
ELSE Sum([PL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk]) / @Credits
END AS [Yield]
   , CASE WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5870 THEN [ICP].[UnitCost] 
WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5730 THEN [ICP].[UnitCost] - 0.25 
WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5990 THEN [ICP].[UnitCost] * 0 
ELSE [ICP].[UnitCost]
END AS [UC]
   , CASE WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5870 THEN [ICP].[UnitCost] * SUM(Sum([PL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk]) / @Credits) OVER (PARTITION BY [PC].[ProductCategoryCode])
WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5730 THEN ([ICP].[UnitCost] - 0.25) * SUM(Sum([PL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk]) / @Credits) OVER (PARTITION BY [PC].[ProductCategoryCode])
WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5990 THEN ([ICP].[UnitCost] * 0) * SUM(Sum([PL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk]) / @Credits) OVER (PARTITION BY [PC].[ProductCategoryCode])
ELSE [ICP].[UnitCost] * SUM(Sum([PL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk]) / @Credits) OVER (PARTITION BY [PC].[ProductCategoryCode])
END AS [Value]
   , 
 **SUM(Sum([PL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk]) / @Credits * [ICP].[UnitCost]) OVER
 (PARTITION BY (CASE WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] IN (5870, 5730, 5990)
 THEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] 
                         END) 
) AS [TotalValue]**
 FROM (((( IC_Products [PC] 
    INNER JOIN  DC_Transactions [DCT] 
     ON [PC].ProductKey = [DCT].ProductKey)
    INNER JOIN  AR_Customers [ARC] 
     ON [DCT].CustomerKey = [ARC].CustomerKey)
    INNER JOIN  IC_ProductLots [PL] 
     ON [DCT].LotKey = [PL].LotKey)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  IC_ProductCosts [ICP] 
     ON ICP.ProductKey=PC.ProductKey and ICP.ProductCostCode=5)
 WHERE 
    ([PL].ProductionDate >= { ts '2015-07-10 00:00:00' }   AND ([PL].ProductionDate <= { ts '2015-07-10 00:00:00' } OR [PL].ProductionDate Is Null)) 
AND ((1=1)  AND [ARC].CustomerKey IN (39) ) 
 GROUP BY 
     CASE WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5870 THEN 'Trimmings' 
WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5730 THEN 'Rib Tips'
WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5990 THEN 'Skins'
ELSE [PC].[Description1] 
END
   , [ARC].CustomerKey
   , [PC].ProductCategoryCode
   , CASE WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5870 THEN [ICP].[UnitCost] 
WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5730 THEN [ICP].[UnitCost] - 0.25 
WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5990 THEN [ICP].[UnitCost] * 0 
ELSE [ICP].[UnitCost]
END
   , [ICP].UnitCost
   , [PC].ProcessCode
 ORDER BY 
     @Credits - SUM(Sum([PL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk])) OVER () 
   , SUM(SUM(PL.OriginalQuantity_Stk)) OVER
 (PARTITION BY (CASE WHEN PC.ProductCategoryCode IN (5870, 5730, 5990)
 THEN PC.ProductCategoryCode
 END)
)
```

*Part of code I need assistance with.

Answer (score 0):

I not sure about everything else going on but for the case statement I think this should work for you

```
SUM(CASE WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5780 OR [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] < 5700 THEN [PL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk] ELSE 0 END) / @Credits * [ICP].[UnitCost]
```

Comment: I get the error "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery."

Comment: @Austin i think i fixed it if not i will remove this answer

Comment: That works in a sense but it still doesn't create a grand total of the values to save as [Total Value].

Comment: @Austin Is grand total the suppose to be the last row or another column ? If you want it as last row, you could create this into a CTE and add a union with the sums of each column to total them.

Comment: I was just going to do it as another column and make that column a header (using the DBMS I use)